# Javascript: Paycheck Calculator (having trouble getting the correct number to show)

Tags: javascript, forms

To practice my javascript skills, I took on a side project creating a paycheck calculator. I am running into issues with my 'if...else' statement. For the life of me, I can't get the correct tax rate to show based on the user's input. No matter what I enter, the console shows .10

Here is the HTML:

```js
const userSalary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const button = document.querySelector('.calculate');

if (parseInt(userSalary.value) >= 100000) {
  var taxRate = 0.37;
} else {
  var taxRate = 0.10;
}

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(parseInt(taxRate));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">
  <form>
    <label for="contribution">Enter contribution percentage</label>
    <input type="number" id="contribution" name="contribution"><br><br>

    <label for="salary">Enter your annual salary:</label>
    <input type="text" id="salary" name="salary"><br><br>

    <label for="tax">Select your tax filing status:</label>
    <select id="tax">
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="married_joint">Married Filing Jointly</option>
      <option value="married_separately">Married Filing Separately</option>
      <option value="head_household">Head of Household</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label for="paycheck_frequency">Paycheck Frequency</label>
    <select id="paycheck_frequency">
      <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
      <option value="biweekly">Biweekly</option>
      <option value="twice_monthly">Twice a Month</option>
      <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
    </select>
  </form>

</body>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
const userSalary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const button = document.querySelector('.calculate');

if (parseInt(userSalary.value) >= 100000) {
  var taxRate = 0.37;
} else {
  var taxRate = 0.10;
}

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(parseInt(taxRate));
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have code before the opening body tag

Comment: You need to run the if-else statement inside the click handler, currently, it's just ran once when the program loads

Comment: Hint: What's `parseInt(0.10)`? What does the "int" part mean? I'm not sure why you're parsing what's *already* a numerical value.

Comment: @tadman that too

Comment: You should also use `let` instead of `var` and declare your variable once, not conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "if-else" block runs when the page loads. At that time, userSalary.value is nothing. Why? Because no one has entered anything into that input yet.

You want your "if-else" block to run when the user clicks the button. So move it into your event listener. Then it behaves as you want and recalculates the tax rate each time the button is clicked. Hope it helps.

```js
const userSalary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const button = document.querySelector('.calculate');

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (parseInt(userSalary.value) >= 100000) {
     var taxRate = 0.37;
  } else {
     var taxRate = 0.10;
  }
  console.log("User Salary value:", parseInt(userSalary.value));
  console.log("Tax Rate:", taxRate);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="contribution">Enter contribution percentage</label>
      <input type="number" id="contribution" name="contribution"><br><br>

      <label for="salary">Enter your annual salary:</label>
      <input type="text" id="salary" name="salary"><br><br>

      <label for="tax">Select your tax filing status:</label>
      <select id="tax">
        <option value="single">Single</option>
        <option value="married_joint">Married Filing Jointly</option>
        <option value="married_separately">Married Filing Separately</option>
        <option value="head_household">Head of Household</option>
      </select><br><br>

        <label for="paycheck_frequency">Paycheck Frequency</label>
        <select id="paycheck_frequency">
          <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
          <option value="biweekly">Biweekly</option>
          <option value="twice_monthly">Twice a Month</option>
          <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
      </select>
    </form>

  </body>
    <button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following javascript instead:

```js
const userSalary = document.querySelector('#salary');
const button = document.querySelector('.calculate');

let taxRate;

function recalculateTaxRate() {
  if (parseInt(userSalary.value) >= 100000) {
    taxRate = 0.37;
  } else {
    taxRate = 0.10;
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // Recalculate the rate before printing it.
  recalculateTaxRate();
  console.log(taxRate);
});
```